# stringify/parse edn in clojure/ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

In JavaScript one can turn a js data structure into a JSON string via

```
JSON.stringify({somedata: { somesubdata: {}}})
```

And somewhere else, one can parse it again into a JS data structure via

```
var my_obj = JSON.parse("{"somedata":{"some_subdata":{}}}");
```

What would be the equivalent in Clojure/ClojureScript for the edn format?

I want to stringify some data on a ClojureScript front-end and parse it on a Clojure back-end. (and vice versa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure & ClojureScript: clojure.core/read-string, clojure.edn/read-string and cljs.reader/read-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661655/clojure-clojurescript-clojure-core-read-string-clojure-edn-read-string-and-c)

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate of this question, though an answer to this question is contained in part of the first answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, a very detailed answer to this question can be found at the referenced link above.

After reading this, a quick answer, maybe especailly for people coming from JavaScript, would be:

in Clojure:

```
parse: clojure.edn/read-string
stringify: prn-str
```

in ClojureScript:

```
parse: cljs.reader/read-string
stringify: prn-str
```