# How to customize the dispatch macro of cljs.reader.read-string for "#(...)"

Tags: clojurescript

Is it possible to customize `cljs.reader/read-string` to handle something like `"#(f 123)"`?

I tried this:

```
(cljs.reader/register-tag-parser! \( (fn [x] "test"))
(cljs.reader/read-string "#(f 123")
```

but get:

> Could not find tag parser for (f in ("inst" "uuid" "queue" "js" "(")

**Update:**

after a little more digging I came across https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/6ff80dc2f309f961d2e363148b5c0da65ac320f9/src/test/cljs/cljs/pprint_test.cljs#L106 which confirms that this isn't currently possible:

```
(simple-tests pprint-reader-macro-test
  ;;I'm not sure this will work without significant work on cljs. Short story, cljs
  ;;reader only takes valid EDN, so #(* % %) won't work.
  ;;see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25712675/546321 for more details
  #_(with-pprint-dispatch code-dispatch
    (write (reader/read-string "(map #(first %) [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7]])")
           :stream nil))
  #_"(map #(first %) [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7]])"
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag in [tagged literals](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#tagged_literals) needs to be a qualified symbol (you can use a unqualified one, but it's discouraged). Symbols can't include parentheses (or other delimiters), because clojure(script) code needs to be a valid s-expression.

If you want to be hacky about it, though, from the error message you can see that the cljs reader thinks the tag is `(f` and not `(`. So, if you do

```
(cljs.reader/register-tag-parser! "(f" (fn [x] "test"))
```

it will work (in the current cljs, it'll probably break at some point).

Comment: yeah sure, I'm basically asking how to extend what the `dispatch-macros` function does (https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/57819844b5a8da0464832f82426ac57ebdf2eaea/src/main/cljs/cljs/reader.cljs#L443) by way of the `*tag-table*` both of which are used disjunctively in `read-dispatch` so it seemed there might be a way. the expression inside the parens is variable so I can't hard-code `"(f"`.